# Customizing Identity Model with Blazor Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am evaluating Blazor Server (.net core 3.1) and am encountering a strange issue right at the outset of creating a test app.

Typically, with MVC & EF, you'd add / extend the ApplicationUser class and insert additional properties. When you add a migration, the database model is updated with these properties. This usually works well and allows the storing of additional of properties to each user e.g. DateOfBirth.

In my BlazorServer project, I've scaffolded the "views" and updated all references from `IdentityUser` to a custom `ApplicationUser` class that I've created:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string IdentityNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I've updated the `Startup.cs` file accordingly:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<ApplicationUser>>();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        ...
    }
```

One would expect that EF would be able to determine that I'm using a custom `IdentityUser` class in the application and create a corresponding migration, however, the migration is still relying on the `IdentityUser` model, see below migration output for the `Up()` method:

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        ...
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUsers",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                UserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
                LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            },
            ...
```

Am I using the correct approach? I found a tutorial [here](https://mvc.tech/blog/blazoridentityuser/) that follows this process but appears to work. I'm not looking for advice on scaffolding etc. This is purely around the migration not picking up the additional properties. I'm happy to add them in manually but if I'm missing an important step relevant to Blazor, I'd like to know and understand how to change my approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you inherit from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`? :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

Comment: What's interesting is that the ApplicationDBContext did inherit it `ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext` but it didn't explicitly specify the Type `IdentityUser` so I didn't think to specify it! Thanks